# Strange : X-CSRF-TOKEN works sometime but some time its not in laravel 5.2 with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5

I am working with  laravel 5.2 and angularjs.  I am generating token in html file like

```
<script>

angular.module("heliops").constant("CSRF_TOKEN", '<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>');
 </script>
```

Sending this token into login request like

```
    $http.post("authenticateAndLogin",{"email":$scope.loginData.email,"password":btoa($scope.loginData.password),"_token":CSRF_TOKEN}   
        ).success(...
```

**But problem is :** Sometime login works while some time its not. Can anyone help ?

Comment: I have same issue, it works fine but doesn't work other time, I checked few things :
1) Cookie is not set as httpOnly - If this is set then JavaScript won't be able to access cookie.

Answer (score 0):

From [laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#csrf-x-xsrf-token):

> #### X-XSRF-TOKEN
>
> Laravel also stores the CSRF token in a XSRF-TOKEN cookie. You can use
> the cookie value to set the X-XSRF-TOKEN request header. Some
> JavaScript frameworks, like **Angular**, do this automatically for you. It
> is **unlikely that you will need to use this value manually**.

Comment: I know this, why some time I can login ?